# Adding Custom Loss for Validation to the Keras.History object

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a loss function which includes several contributions, i.e.
L=L1+L2+... .

I am in particular interested in the individual development of L1,L2... on both the training and validation data set during learning.

If I generate my model via subclassing (and Functional API) and perform the training via model.fit(), how can I add the validation losses maybe called "val_L1", "Val_L2"... to the History-Object?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. I hope this will help someone in future who is also struggling with this issue.
If you define your customized model as the subclass of tf.keras.Model you have to use functions "train_step" and "test_step" via
`def train_step (....):` and `def test_step (...):`.
"train_step" is the function which is used to describe the training procedure according model.fit().

if both functions return:
`return {'L1':L1, 'L2':L2}`
the history-object will contain automatically 'val_L1' and 'val_L2'